# How can I add an error message to response for 404 in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to add an error message to response for 404 error.
I have some method in controller:

```
def method
    *some logic*

    if something.present?
      render json: something, serializer: SomeSerializer
    else
      render json: { errors: I18n.t('errors.something.no_something') }, status: :not_found
    end
  end
```

But when I make a request via postman, the 404 page of the project is shown, without an error output

How can I show a specific error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby on Rails returns the default `404 not found` error page automatically when specific exceptions are raised, for example, `ActionController::RoutingError` or `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

In your code example and with your description, it is likely that an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` was already raised somewhere in the code before you actually reached the `if something.present?` condition.

A simple solution might be to rescue from that exception and return your custom error message in the controller method, like this:

```
def method
  *some logic*
  
  render json: something, serializer: SomeSerializer
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render json: { errors: I18n.t('errors.something.no_something') }, status: :not_found
end
```

end

Another option would be to load records from the database in a way that doesn't raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception when not found, and instead handle missing records on your own.

What that might look like depends, of course, on your specific code (that you didn't share). If you had code like this:

```
something = Something.find(params[:id]) # raises exception when not found
```

then you could change it to:

```
something = Something.find_by(id: params[:id]) # returns nil when not found

if something.present?
  render json: something, serializer: SomeSerializer
else
  render json: { errors: I18n.t('errors.something.no_something') }, status: :not_found
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We decided to just display this error on the frontend, by displaying an object with a state of nil, which they will process on their side :)

```{ something: nil }```